# How do I sort my output

Tags: linux, centos, grep

```
fdisk -l |grep Disk |grep xvd |awk ' {print $1, $2, $3} '
```

Output is

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 42.9
Disk /dev/xvdl: 21.5
Disk /dev/xvdm: 21.5
Disk /dev/xvdj: 2147
Disk /dev/xvdk: 8589
Disk /dev/xvdd: 1073
Disk /dev/xvde: 1073
Disk /dev/xvdb: 21.5
Disk /dev/xvdc: 1073
Disk /dev/xvdh: 2147
Disk /dev/xvdi: 2147
Disk /dev/xvdf: 10.7
Disk /dev/xvdg: 42.9
Disk /dev/xvdn: 10.7
```

I want the middle column sorted so that xvda is on top and xvdn is on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Because column 1 is all the same, and you want normal sort order. You can use `sort` with no arguments. Just pipe it into `sort`.

You can cut the number of commands e.g.

```
fdisk -l |grep "Disk.*xvd" |awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' |sort
```

or

```
fdisk -l | awk '/Disk.*xvd/ {print $1, $2, $3}' | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fdisk -l |grep Disk |grep xvd |awk ' {print $1, $2, $3} ' | sort -V -k 2
```

Comment: You may want to flesh this out a bit